# Print function, hello world in C

Tags: c

Started reading C a few days back, I'm trying to learn how to split my code into functions, can anyone tell me why my code not printing `hello world` for me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PRINT() {
    printf("hello world");
}

int main() {
   void PRINT();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the section in your book on function prototypes yet?

Comment: Also, add a `\n` to your string `printf("hello world\n");` in case you meet buffering issues.

Comment: @StephenNewell I have indeed, this was just shortly to test if i understood it.

I take it it's where you call the prototype before main, and then have the actual function below main, correct?

Comment: Alright, got it, thanks for the quick reponds guys!

Comment: Also in C, all uppercase names are generally reserved for macros, while C generally encourages the use of all lowercase for variables and function names. I wouldn't be surprised if there were a number of `PRINT` macros that may conflict. Case in C is a matter of style, so you are free to do as you please, but be aware that can lead to the wrong first-impression in some circles.

Comment: maybe accept an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should call the function like this:

```
int main() {    
  PRINT();
}
```

Comment: Yup — the `void PRINT();` in `main()` is a stray, unnecessary, non-prototype declaration of `PRINT()`, not a call to it.

Answer (score 6):

The `void` part isn't needed. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

or try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PRINT() {

    printf("Hello World");
}

int main() {    

    PRINT();
}
```

Make sure to `#include <stdio.h>` at the top.

Comment: The `return 0;` has been optional since C99 was defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function inside the `main()` function of type void `void PRINT();`.

This is a [function definition](https://www.w3schools.com/c/c_functions_decl.php).

Instead of `void PRINT()`, invoke the function with `PRINT();`.

Comment: `void PRINT();` is not a definition, it is a declaration.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to call a function, you should not put data types before your function's name.
try this :

```
int main()
{
   
    PRINT();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not necessarily true, @yahcraft... for example, if a function returns a value and you want to ignore it, `(void) f(x);` indicates that you are ignoring that return value... likewise `int x = (int)function_returning_float();` is casting the result...